# Questions about the euclidean topology

Tags: general-topology, definition

My general topology textbook just gave the definition of euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ but unfortunately did not provide any examples and I was hopping that someone here could help me with some questions I have. The definition they gave is the following:

> A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is said to be open in the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ if it has the following property:
>
> (1)$\ \ \ \  $For each $x \in S$, there exists $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, with $a<b$, such that $x \in ]a,b[\subseteq S$.

My questions are the following:

- Let $A=[1,2]$ then we can define an interval $]1-\epsilon,2+\epsilon[$ and then we would have that $[1,2]\subset ]1-\epsilon,2+\epsilon[$, wouldn't that mean that $[1,2]$ is opened?
- Let $A=]1,2[\ \cup\ ]3,4[$,

we can define a new interval $]1,4[$ such that $\forall x\in A,x\in ]1,4[$. But it is not true that $]1,4[\subseteq A$. Rather we have that $A \subseteq ]1,4[$. So the set $A$ does not have property (1) thus not being opened.

On the other hand, $]1,2[$ and $]3,4[$ are opened and the union of open sets is also opened. Since $A =]1,2[\ \cup\ ]3,4[$ then $A$ must be opened. So is $A$ opened or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $[1,2]$ is not open, because there are no numbers $a$ and $b$, with $a<b$, such that $1\in(a,b)$ and that $(a,b)\subset[1,2]$.

And $(1,2)\cup(3,4)$ is open. For instance, if $x\in(1,2)$ and $r=\min\{|x-1|,|x-2|\}$, then $(x-r,x+r)\subset(1,2)\subset(1,2)\cup(3,4)$.

Comment: Yes but we have to find one interval for all values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ right? If we chose $(x - r, x + r)$ with $r=\text{min}\{|x - 1|,|x - 2|\}$ then it is only true that $x \in (x - r, x + r)$. Right?

Comment: What do you mean? With that $r$ that I chose, you have $x\in(x-r,x+r)$ and you also have $(x-r,x+r)\subset(1,2)\cup(3,4)$. What more do you need?

Comment: If we let $x= 3.5$, then $x \in (1,2) \cup (3,4)$, and $r=\text{min}\{2.5,1.5\}$, therefore the interval will be $(3.5 - 1.5,3.5 + 1.5)=(2,5)$ and it is not true that $(2,5) \subset (1,2) \cup (3,4) $

Comment: I specificaly wrote that $x\in(1,2)$. If $x\in(3,4)$, then you take $r=\min\{|x-3|,|x-4|\}$.

Comment: My question about the definition is: The interval we find such that $x \in ]a,b[ \subset S$. Does that interval have to be the same for all choices of $x$, or we can have different intervals for different values of $x$?

Comment: It *has* to be different for different choices of $x$.

Comment: That makes more sense. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You have overlooked a key part of the definition:

> **for each $x \in S$** there exists $a,b \in \mathbb R$, with $a<b$, such that $x \in \, ]a,b[ \, \subset S$.

So, given $A = [1,2]$ and $x = 1$, do the required values $a,b$ exist?

Comment: As a complement, you can prove from the definition that a set $S$ is open if and only if this set $S$ can be written as a (possibly infinite) union of open intervals $(a_i, b_i)$. As a rule of thumb, this alternative characterization is useful for proving that a set is open, if your set $S$ is not open usually the way to prove it is to find a point $x\in S$ such that no open interval around $x$ is contained in $S$.